# Keyboard Shortcut To Fix Error In NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

In NetBeans, what's the keyboard shortcut to open the list of possible solutions to an error? 
The button is to the left of an error and looks like a little light bulb. 
I would like to use this without reaching for my mouse.

Comment: my google-fu must be weak today. Did not find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Shortcut is Alt+Enter. It is also accessible in Source/Fix Code.

Comment: https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference/